# The compositionality of classical logic

Tags: logic

Could someone please explain in simple words why classical logic is said to be compositional? In the case of classical logic is this the same as saying that it is truth-functional?

Comment: Can you add some context? I have never heard this word used for logics.

Comment: Do you mean compositional in the sense of formal natural language semantics as described [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/faculty/davise/ai/semantics.html)?

Answer (score 3):

A semantics is compositional if the meaning of a complex expression is a function of its parts and the way they are put together.

FOL can said to be **compositional**: The semantic evaluation (for formulas, the denotation will be a truth value) of a formula like $\neg \forall x (woman(x) \to \neg laugh(x))$ is completely determined by the meaning of the individual parts ($x$, $woman$, $laugh$, $\to$, $\neg$, $\exists$) and the way these individual parts are put together. The definition of the evaluation of a formula provides us with an algorithm that step by step assembles the semantic value of the complex formula by going through the structure of the formula. Once we have a model and know the interpretations of $woman$ and $laugh$, for example, and once we know that we put these parts together as $woman(x) \to laugh(x)$ and not e.g. as $laugh(x) \to woman(x)$), the semantic value of $woman(x) \to \neg laugh (x)$ is uniquely determined by its parts and the way they are combined, without ambiguities or irregularities; hence, first-order logic is compositonal.

However, this is not the same as being **truth-functional**. Truth-functional means that the semantic value of an expression is a truth value that is completely determined by the truth values of the sub-expressions. For example, logical connectives like $\land$ are truth-functional: The semantic value of an expression $p \land q$ solely depends on the truth of $p$ and $q$. In contrast, natural language words like "but" are usually not truth-functional: There is more (pragmatic) meaning to a statement like "He is young *but* smart" than just asserting that $young(x)$ is true and $smart(x)$ is true and hence the sentence is true. In natural language, other than in classical logic, not every aspect of meaning can be determined by functions that operate only on truth values. Still, the fact that a language is not truth-functional doesn't necessarily mean it can't be compositional: The semantics of a complex expression could well be fully determined by the semantics of its individual parts and its syntax, just that this semantics involves more than operations on truth values.

**So I don't think it's correct to say that "in classical logic, compositionality is the same as truth-functionality" - these are two different principles, it's just that in classical logic, both principles happen to be applicable.**

Judging by your post history, it seems like you are coming from a philosophy/natural language semantics point of view, so I'll elaborate more on that side:
DRT (Discourse Representation Theory), in case you have heard if it, is an example of such a non-truth-functional but compositional theory of meaning.
Consider again the sentence $\neg \forall x (woman(x) \to laugh(x))$. Logically, this is equivalent to $\exists x (woman(x) \land \neg laugh(x))$. The first sentence expresses "Not every woman laughs", the second "A woman does not laugh". If we take meaning as completely truth-functional, the two formalizations have the same semantics: Since they are true in all the same situations, truth-functionality tells us that they are semantically identical. This is what FOL tells us.
However, this is not quite how these sentence behave in natural language. The second sentence, "Some woman does not laugh", could be continued by something like "She cries". This is not possible with the first sentence: "Not every woman laughs. * She cries." is a strange utterance. Now if the two formulations were semantically identical, then how can it be that they behave differently when combined with the same sentence? Clearly, truth-conditions, as FOL gives us, can not be the sole key to meaning.
Nevertheless, we wouldn't want to say that our language is non-compositional just because truth conditions don't suffice to explain all of the semantics. DRT provides a way to account for this difference in discourse behavior. While the two formalizations are logically equivalent, they will have a different representation in DRT, which explains their difference in meaning. Under a proper interpretation procedure, which does not rely solely on truth functions, the semantic evaluation of the DRT representations will be compositional. This shows that there is no need to abandon compositionality just because truth-functionality as in FOL doesn't suffice.

If you are further interested, I would recommend you subsubchapter 7.4.5 "DRT and compositionality" in the following book:
*Gamut, L.T.F., 1990. Logic, language, and meaning. Volume 2: Intensional logic and logical grammar.*
This chapter is basically a more elaborate version of what I wrote in my last paragraph. However, it might be necessary to have basic knowledge of DRT to be able to completely make sense of it.

Comment: I'm not sure what "semantic value" exactly means. Is it just a synonym of "meaning"?

Comment: @Mijito Yes, these two terms are more or less exchangeable here.

Answer (score 2):

With many logics now formulated, one could easily maintain that the expression "classical logic" is vague. What is available today has origins in Aristotle's term logic but is not term logic. Visit the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy and read the entry on "logical constants" to see how the evolution from term logic to compositional logic changed the subject matter.

Logic became compositional when "the function concept" had been introduced into logic. Any basic algebra book will explain function composition. Given,

y = f(x) and y = g(x)

you can form a new function,

y= f(g(x))

You may compare the well-formed formulas of a formal system with algebraic formulas in which operators like addition and multiplication are applied to arguments from the most deeply nested parentheses first,

( 3 + 2 ) + 6

5 + 6

11

Truth-functionality is associated with the compositionality of systems that interpret words like "and" and "or" as functions that yield truth or falsity when its two arguments can be said to be true or false. Look up switching functions and Boolean polynomials to see this without the added baggage of logic.

The formal representation of term logic introduces a different notion of compositionality. If one is given the statement,

"Plato is a man"

one may replace the proper name with a variable intended to represent the denotation of an individual,

"x is a man"

Now, truth or falsity depends upon what one substitutes for "x" in that expression (it is no longer a statement). As in algebra, one may build formulas from expressions with variables,

( x + y ) + z

But, when logical expressions evaluate to truth or falsity, the operators which connect them must, itself, evaluate to truth or falsity. So, truth-functional compositionality is fundamental to the notion of compositional logics.